# How can I replace wrong spaces in a text using REGEX?

Tags: regex, replace, atom-editor

I am trying to figure out how to replace spaces in a text like the example below but I don't know how to deal with different number of spaces in the same text

This text:

```
E m  se guida,  a  e mpre sa  deu  ba ixa  e m 
cerca  de  $82  b ilhões   ( ma is  de  75 %)  de  se us  a t ivos.
```

Should be:

```
Em seguida, a empresa deu baixa em 
cerca de $82 bilhões (mais de 75%) de seus ativos.
```

Note that there are single spaces between characters and double spaces between words.

Could someone give me some light on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would approach this in two steps.  First, I would use a regex to replace all of the single spaces, and then another to shorten the double spaces.  To find only single spaces, you can use this regex:

`(\S)\s(\S)`

Next, to find double spaces, you can use this regex:

`\s\s+`

So first, replace single spaces with groups one and two from the first regex, and then replace double spaces with a single space using the second regex.

Using the atom editor, you can use these two regex to find and replace like this:

[image]
[image]

In the second image, **you do have to enter one space**, it is slightly unclear from the screen shot.  Hope this helps!